# 16-bit binary arithmetic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Javascript has only one number type: a 64-bit floating point.

Using Javascript, I need to implement a hashing algorithm which is designed to be written in `C` with 16 bit unsigned integers.

The main operation is something like this (pseudocode):

```
uint16 n = 0;
string s = "abcd1234";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i += 1) {
    n ^= (n << 2) + (n >> 3) + s[i];
}

return n;
```

Of course, this produces one result when using `uint16` values and a different result if `n` is a 64-bit floating point.

My best solution to the problem so far is to convert the results of each bitwise operation to <= 16 bits, using a function like this (javascript):

```
function uint16 (n) {
    return parseInt(n.toString(2).slice(-16), 2);
}
```

and performing the operation something like this (javascript):

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i +=1 ) {
    n ^= uint16(uint16(n << 2) + uint16(n >>> 3) + s.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

but I'm not 100% confident this will always produce the correct results.

Is there any standard way to emulate 16-bit unsigned bitwise operations on a number value in Javascript?

Comment: Float is not the only number type in Javascript – there are integers. Any bitwise operation on a float rounds the number down to an integer. `3.5 << 1 == 6`, or `10.9 | 0 == 10`, for example. It is still true that the results might be different for 32-bit and 16-bit integers, however. @Amit provides a way to convert a number to a '16-bit' int by trimming it … But you should maybe have a look into JS TypedArrays, Uint16Array, for example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND).

It operates on 32 bit integers, but you can just "and" with 0xffff.

```
function uint16 (n) {
  return n & 0xFFFF;
}
```

Additionally, bit shift operations (`<<`, `>>>`) also operate on 32 bit integers, so you only really need to call the `uint16` function before assignment:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i +=1 ) {
  n ^= uint16((n << 2) + (n >>> 3) + s.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks - ANDing looks like a good idea, but I dont understand how just trimming the result at the end would work.  I think of it like working on a 16-bit value in a 32-bit container.. wouldnt a `>>>` potentially bring in higher order bits that would have been 0 if working with a true 16-bit value?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - yes, you're right.. you do need intermediate operations

Comment: As an aside- if you want 16 bit *signed* integers, you can use `(n << 16 >> 16)`, which will sign extend the left 16 bits of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect @Amit's version will execute faster but this is a workaround I have had success with:

```
//create a typed container, we'll work only in the first index.
const idx = 0;
const n = new Uint16Array(1);

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i += 1) {
    n[idx] ^= (n[idx] << 2) + (n[idx] >> 3) + s[i];
}
```